# Does Task Scheduler trigger fire for each time the task is started?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have a task with a trigger that says "After triggered, repeat every 5 minutes indefinitely."

I had set the task up to run once when it was created and then it repeated every 5 minutes as expected. However, I also manually started the job a few times to test it. My question is whether the "repeat every 5 minutes indefinitely" trigger was triggered for each time I manually started it?

In other words, if I manually started it 5 times does that mean it will be firing an additional 5 times per minute or is Task Scheduler smart enough to know the trigger is still running and not fire it multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not.

Manual task start is completely separate from any triggers, and you set repeat in one of the triggers.

You may check this yourself by adding action to display message (if your Windows will tell you it's deprecated, add action to launch `MSG.EXE` with parameters `* /v /SERVER:localhost Task triggered!`).

Also, scheduler behaviour when trigger worked, but previously started process is still running, is explicitly configurable in same GUI, and by default it skips the run:

[image]